# Xcopy, how to not copy empty folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

Here is the code.

```
xcopy /c/s/z "%appdata%" "./backup"
```

Is there a way to make it not copy folders with nothing in them?

Comment: type `xcopy /?` in the console and read the help message; you will find switch `/s` there...

Comment: Consider Robocopy as a better alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying the /s switch, the xcopy statement will ignore empty directories and subdirectories by default.